# What is the name of this font ? What template use it?

Tags: fonts, templates

I wonder what font is used for the title and sections of this document :
 [image]

I really like it and want to use it. Any example of templates that use it ? Thanks.

Comment: I already looked to that answer before asking my question, but here I didn't had access to a pdf file ; only to a jpg image. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a document made with the KOMA-Script `scrartcl` class.

Comment: I tried with this package but here is the result http://i.imgur.com/KxaOWLv.png, you can see that the font is not the same. I don't understand because, if I look on internet, the above image seems to come from Koma-script indeed...